# Backward compatibility of @orderColumn: hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have 2 entities with oneToMany relationship. I want to maintain the insertion order for child entity. I used @orderColumn for that. Code:

Parent Class:

```
@Entity
public class Order{

  private String orderId;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
  @NotEmpty
  @OrderColumn
  private List<OrderItem> orderItems = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Child class:

```
@Entity
public class OrderItem{

  @Id
  private String orderItemId;
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", nullable = false)
  private Order order;  
}
```

The issue that I'm facing here is orderColumn is not backward compatible. i.e. it adds an column in the child table with name "order_item_order". It works fine for the records that are getting created after this change but for the previous records, the column is null and it results in below exception:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: null index column for collection
```

I have tried setting the default value to 0 for the column. In that case it returns only one record for child.

Suggestions please.

Comment: Do you have a creation_date column in the `OrderItem` table ? If yes, you may use the `@OrderBy("creation_date")` to order without having to add a column

Comment: No, I don't. That's why had to go with orderColumn.

Answer (score 0):

You have two solutions :

- Proceed with the `@OrderColumn` but fill it with the right values : index starting at 0, incrementing by 1 (migrate your data thanks to a sql scripts or a two steps migration from java)
- Proceed with `@OrderBy` annotation : add a `creation_date` column, fill it when you store the object (like in the `create(ModelClass model)` method of your repository) and set it to a default value in the past